# Comunicación entre un código c # y la conexión hsp en raspberry pi3

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

Mi duda es esta tengo que  hacer comunicar mi codigo c# en el terminal de raspberry y en conexión con HSP osea que debo escribir en el terminal normal y verlo en el segundo, pero quando voi a escribir mono /home/CA_fileRaspberry/CA_fileRaspberry/bin/Debug/CA_fileRaspberry.exe me lo escribe solo in el terminal raspberry [image: este es el codigo c#] 
[image: esto es lo que sale en el terminal]
[image: esto es lo que veo]

es un proyecto escolar asi que tengo que usar c# etcetera gracias por la ayuda

Comment: esa aplicacion que muestras ejecuta dentro del raspberry o desde una pc ? no entendi la comunicacion con quien debes realizar

Comment: de una pc, gracias por la yuda pero ya resolvi, el problema esta en un comando del visual studio mal echo